# custom list view with check Box does not work

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a problem my custom List view.I have data in hash map and add into array list which is shown in below code.what is my problem is in my hash map contain 20 values and i try set into the list view but first data only display other or not.Thanks advance

This is my CustomAdapter

package com.example.node10.databasetesting;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import static com.example.node10.databasetesting.DataBase.*;

public class ListViewEmployee extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    private Button btn_view;
    private Button btn_submit;
    ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,String>> emp;
    HashMap<Integer,String> map;
    Set<Integer> keyValue;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_employee);
        DataBase dataBase=new DataBase(this);
        map=new HashMap<>();
        map=dataBase.getValueEmpTable();
        emp=new ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, String>>();
        keyValue=map.keySet();
        emp.add(map);


        btn_view= (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_btn_emp_view);
        btn_view.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       if(v.getId()==R.id.id_btn_emp_view){
           displayList();
          // selectItem();
       }


    }



    private void displayList() {

        //create the Arrayt adapter
        ListView listview= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.id_listview);
        final MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.custom_listview,emp);

       listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }




    public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<Integer,String>>{
        boolean[] checkBoxState;
        ViewHolder viewholder;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource,ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,String>> map) {
            super(context, resource, map);
            // create the boolean array for check box selection
            checkBoxState= new boolean[map.size()];
        }
        // create the class for caching the view
        class ViewHolder{
            TextView txtView;
            CheckBox checkBox;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView==null){
                LayoutInflater objlayout= (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView=objlayout.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview,null);
                viewholder=new ViewHolder();
                viewholder.txtView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_checkbox_textview);
                viewholder.checkBox= (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_checkbox);

                convertView.setTag(viewholder);

            }else{
                viewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();}


           // viewholder.txtView.setText(emp.get(position).toString());

            viewholder.txtView.setText(emp.get(position).get(position+1).toString());
            viewholder.checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
            viewholder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                        checkBoxState[position] = true;

                    } else {
                        checkBoxState[position] = false;
                    }
                }
            });




            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: sry for my poor english.........

Comment: What is problem in current code?

Comment: Problem is  final int position . Remove the final. It only executes once (for first element). Do not use checkBoxState[position] inside the getView method.

Comment: In hash map contain integer and string value.i want to place all the string value into list view .but  first record only displayed.this is my problem..

Comment: @AbdullahTellioglu it does not work

Comment: There are some problems in this code. First of all why do you save boolean array in adapter. Second of all, you are using View Holder pattern wrongly.

Check out this link :
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html
Don't create the single ViewHolder in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Now you put to your adapter ArrayList of HashMap. I don't know why are you doing that, but now your ArrayList emp contains ony one element - that was added in line

```
emp.add(map);
```

So, ArrayAdapter for array with size = 1 will show 1 elemet.
If you want to show in list all elements from your map. I suggest to use 
ArrayList emp and comvert map to list by using map.values()

```
ArrayList<String> emp = (ArrayList<String>)map.values();
```

Then change your adapter to

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
```